# Newly created Cross-Platform Xamarin.Forms project fails to build after updating NuGet Packages

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm trying to create a cross platform mobile app with Xamarin.forms in Visual Studio Community 2017 (version 15.9.5).

After creating the project I update the NuGet packages and receive 3 errors and 1 warning (to note: I didn't write any code at all).

Below you can find a detailed process of what I do and detailed error messages.

I click on File > New > Project > Visual C# > Cross-Platform > Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms).

I name my project and I'm prompted to choose a template, I select "Blank App".

For platform I choose all 3 (iOS, Android, UWP), and as code sharing strategy I choose "Shared Project".

After the project has been created I open the NuGet Package Manager and update all of my packages, here you can see them in their latest version.[image: PackageList]
Once the packages are updated I receive 7 warnings and 1 error. I clean and rebuild the solution but I keep getting these errors and warnings, although from time to time they change without me changing anything.

I may see 7 warnings and no error, close the project, open it again, rebuild and get 3 errors and 1 warning.

Here is the list of errors at the moment: [image: Errors]

And here is the full output:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   2>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
>   2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
>   3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino.UWP, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3064,2): error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error XA4303: Error extracting resources from "C:\Users\gioel.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.support.compat\28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll": System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error XA4303:    at System.IO.LongPathHelper.Normalize(String path, UInt32 maxPathLength, Boolean checkInvalidCharacters, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error XA4303:    at System.IO.Path.NewNormalizePath(String path, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error XA4303:    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error XA4303:    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error XA4303:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.ExtractAll(ZipArchive zip, String destination, Action`2 progressCallback, Func`2 modifyCallback, Func`2 deleteCallback, Boolean forceUpdate)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error XA4303:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
>   3>  Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino.UWP -> C:\Users\gioel\Documents\Repositories\GitHub\BengalinoUWP\Bencivenga_Gioele_BengalinoApp\Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino\Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino\Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino.UWP\bin\x86\Debug\Bencivenga_Gioele_Bengalino.UWP.exe
>   3>C:\Users\gioel.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk\2.1.2\tools\CoreRuntime\Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime.targets(195,9): error : Framework resource extraction failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 1 skipped ==========

I searched online for a solution and found some old threads where they recommend using LongPathTool in order to get rid of the 260 characters maximum problem but their instructions are "just install it and it will work" and well, doing that isn't making anything work for me.

Thanks for reading the question and even more thanks if you give me any idea or suggestion regarding this problem. Feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your project to the root of `C://`, typically this solves that specific error.

Try to create a folder in `C:\Users\` named XamarinProjects, and put your solution there.

After some digging I found this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If setting this flag does not fix the PathTooLongException error, another approach is to specify a common intermediate output root for projects in your solution by setting IntermediateOutputPath in the project .csproj file. Try to use a relatively short path. For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Projects\MyApp</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

From [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/path-too-long-exception)

Comment: Is this really the only way? I saw it mentioned elsewhere but I would prefer to keep my project where it is

Comment: When I was using Windows, this was the best workaround that I've done.

Comment: Thank you for the update, could you care to explain where I should set that flag? Should I just write it in the XAML code of my shared project's MainWindow?

Comment: Forgot to look at the official documentation you linked, I'll try and report back, thanks again for the help in the meantime.

Comment: No luck, tried both methods but the errors don't go away. Since changing the folder is working for now I'll accept this workaround. Thank you for pointing me to the official solution.

Comment: No problem, I also forgot to tell you where to edit the file, it was the csproj. Like I said previously, what got me working was always changing the path, unfortunately